# Why does the following function not end?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Why does the following function not end?

```
(* funct1 is a different function that does end *)
fun funct(a,b::bs)=let val c=a in funct1(c,a,b::bs); 
= ;
= ;
= ;
= ;
stdIn:15.54-17.2 Error: syntax error: deleting  SEMICOLON SEMICOLON SEMICOLON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is really instructive in this case. The function does not end because you need `end` keyword instead of `;`. This is the syntax for `let...in...end` block in SML.

```
fun funct (a, b::bs) = let val c = a in funct1 (c, a, b::bs) end
```